Trying to read a log file using typescript
How do I read a log file using typescript -- I've tried using fs - but it says the module is not found.
I've tried to use a promise - but then its not resolving.
should I place the test file in the root or src folder?
  let file = "test.txt"
  fetch (file)
    .then(x => x.text())



x.text() returns a promise so you need a second "then".
let file = "test.txt"
fetch (file)
  .then(x => x.text().then(text => console.log(text)))


That console logs the markup of the index file - but not the test.txt - as if I did a right click page source
